# Add an item to a collection just before it starts looping in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

How do I dynamically add another path before looping to Directory.GetDirectories? :

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath))
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        File.Copy(f,"");
    }

}
```

For example I need it like

```
foreach (Directory dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath).Add("another path"))
{ 
//My other code here.... 
}
```

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to loop the subdirectory "another path" of "dirpath"? Or do you want to add a file "another path" to the list? Or do you want a combined list of two directories?

Comment: I just needed what user3185569 has provided me below. But,Why the negative vote for my question?

Comment: No idea, not mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath).Concat(new string[] { "another path"});
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class.

### Side Note on your expected result:

You can't `foreach (Directory dir` because `Directory` is a static class and you can't have an instance of it. But you can use `DirectoryInfo` :

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath)
                    .Concat(new string[] { "another path" })
                    .Select(path => new DirectoryInfo(path));

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
{

}
```

Comment: GetDirectories returns a string array, not list<string>

Comment: @Popam So ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Problem is this : 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Popam It does. Just add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dir = Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath);
dir.Add("another path");
foreach (string d in dir)
 {
     foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
     {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        File.Copy(f,"");
     }
 }
```

Comment: GetDirectories returns a string array, not list<string>

Answer (score 1):

For achieving such a goal you may use a recursive approach like:

```
  public void Fileprocessing(directories){
             foreach (string d in directories)
                            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                                    {
                                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                                        File.Copy(f,"");
                                    }
            }
                if(conditionToAddPath){
                directories.Add("another path");
                Fileprocessing(directories);
                }
    }
```

and when you call the first time initialize your directories like:

...

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath);
Fileprocessing(directories);
```

...

Note: this is a pseudo-coded answer!! please review before implementing or complete this answer by adding ready to use implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

one way using `SelectMany`:

```
var paths = new List<string> { "path1", "path2", "path3" };
var files = paths.SelectMany(Directory.GetDirectories).SelectMany(Directory.GetFiles);
paths.Add("path4");

foreach (var file in files)
    Console.WriteLine(file);
```

another way using `select`:

```
var paths = new List<string> { "path1", "path2", "path3" };
var query = from path in paths
            from dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)
            from file in Directory.GetFiles(dir)
            select file;
paths.Add("path4");

foreach (var file in query)
    Console.WriteLine(file);
```